# Adding route to resource without losing default routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm confused about routing in rails. I have custom actions on a controller called UsersController, such as "login".

In my routes.rb if I do:

```
resource :users do
  collection do
    get  'login'
    post 'login'
    get  'logout'
  end
end
```

I can link to the action login of UsersController no problem but then going to *localhost:3000/users* gives me the error:

> Couldn't find User without an ID

But if I do

> resources :users

*localhost:3000/users* gives me the expected listing.

I tried to put both but only the first version that is present in the file will work as expected.

How can I add routes to the default ones?

Comment: Did you restart the server after you changed your routes.rb?

Comment: Yes I did, it didn't change anything!

Comment: I do not know if its a typo, but it should be resources not resource for the first code block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your routes.

Try `resources`not `resource`. (`resource`doesn't create the #index action)

Take a look to [the manual](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources)

Comment: Oh thanks a lot. I was confusing both forms, thinking resourceS was for when you specified several arguments...